# Cannot watch Kotlin variable in android studio

Tags: debugging, android-studio, kotlin

I am not able to get android studio display the value of a calculation in the watches window.

I use Kotlin for development and when i try to add a value to watches, i get a message which says "An exception occurs during evaluate expression".

e.g.

```
   val model = MyModel()
   val pos = model.position
```

Now if I add `model.position` to watches, then it gives the above error and the value of the expression is not displayed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How is the `MyModel.position` property defined?

Comment: @miensol it is defined as a val in the primary constructor. If i define a simple value like `val width = 30` and watch its value, then it is shown. But the value for any other type accessed with dot syntax is not shown. I'm using `Android Studio 2.2` and `kotlin version 1.0.4`

Comment: downgrade kotlin version to like 1.01

Comment: I have some problems

Comment: I've got the same issue since eons.

Comment: I am getting the same error.Is this resolved ? @vishnus

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's bug in Android studio.

1) I've reported mentioned bug (or very similar) recently:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62859634

2) If you find a bug in tools, report it to Google: 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

This bug should be already fixed in new Dex compiler.

Try to enable it by adding:

```
android.enableD8=true
```

to your gradle.properties.file

For more details check [official blogpost](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/next-generation-dex-compiler-now-in.html).

Comment: @UmutADALI I am sorry to hear that. I wrote the response because I actually had the same error back then (or at least it seemed to be the same one) and this fix worked for me. I tried it right now in the new Android Studio 3.2 and it still works for me. According to the issue mentioned in the response this does work some but unfortunately not for all.

Comment: I try Android Studio 3.2 too and kotlin version 1.3.0 but almost never results

Answer (score 0):

file> invalidate caches / restart .. fixed it for me